# How do I grep and replace string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file which contains my json

```
{
  "type": "xyz",
  "my_version": "1.0.1.66~22hgde",
  }
```

I want to edit the value for key my_version and everytime replace the value after third dot with another number which is stored in a variable so it will become something like 1.0.1.32~22hgde. I am using sed to replace it

```
sed -i "s/\"my_version\": \"1.0.1.66~22hgde\"/\"my_version\": \"1.0.1.$VAR~22hgde\"/g" test.json
```

This works but the issue is that my_version string doesn't remain constant and it can change and the string can be something like this 1.0.2.66 or 2.0.1.66. So how do I handle such case in bash?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier with [jq](https://jqplay.org/s/PUFuOn3EOz)?

Comment: You don't need grep unless you are looking for the file.  sed provided the search and replace capability.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I handle such case?

You write a regular expression to match any possible combination of characters that can be there. You can learn regex with fun with regex crosswords online.

Do not edit JSON files with `sed` - `sed` is for lines. Consider using JSON aware tools - like `jq`, which will handle any possible case.

Comment: sed is a stream-based editor, not a line-based editor.  Adding yet another tool to perform common text-based editing for yet another text-based data format is a maintenance and skill-set nightmare.

Comment: `sed is a stream-based editor, not a line-based editor` `sed` reads input separated by newlines. You can't change the separator (and `-z` is GNU extension). It's hard to edit streams separated by other characters in sed. Ergo, I call it "line-based editor", because the basic chunk of input for editing in sed is a line. It's also "stream-based", in a sense that `sed` can work with a stream (of lines).

Comment: `Adding yet another tool to perform common text-based editing for yet another text-based data format is a maintenance` On the contrary - using a tool specifically created to work with specific data format will result in less bugs and less maintenance. It's not possible to write a JSON parser in `sed`. Bugs resulting from duplicating what already `jq` does very well, duplicating that in `sed` may bite in the long run and result in more maintenance. `and skill-set nightmare` Always has been. Overall, this is subjective and depends on specific use-case.

Comment: Very tactfully stated!

Answer (score 1):

A [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) answer: `file.json` contains

```json
{
  "type": "xyz",
  "my_version": "1.0.1.66~22hgde",
  "object": "can't end with a comma"
  }
```

then, replacing the last octet before the tilde:

```sh
VAR=32
jq --arg octet "$VAR" '.my_version |= sub("[0-9]+(?=~)"; $octet)' file.json
```

outputs

```json
{
  "type": "xyz",
  "my_version": "1.0.1.32~22hgde",
  "object": "can't end with a comma"
}
```